# How to retrieve the model linked to a many to many relation in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, model

I have three models: Wall, Post and Constraint. They all have an id.

```
Post
id

Wall
id

Constraint
id

Post_wall
post_id
wall_id
constraint_id
```

Between Wall and Post I have a ManyToMany relation. In the pivot table of that relation I have a column constraint_id. When I retrieve all the posts linked to a Wall, I also need the Constraint linked in the pivot table.

Right now I can get the constraint_id using the withPivot('constraint_id') method.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Wall')
       ->withPivot('constraint_id')
```

But I want the object, not the id. Is this possible in Laravel?

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Wall')
       ->withPivot('constraint_id')
       ->join('constraints', 'post_wall.constraint_id', '=', 'constraint.id');
```

I also tried to join the constraint table, but then it doesn't return an object.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Check this link, I think you can find your answer here: http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2016/04/06/introducing-laravel-many-to-many-relations/

Comment: At the end of the page you linked I found the ->withPivot('description') method. This returns the description. In my situation this will place the constraint_id in the Post object, but I want the Constraint object in the Post object, not just the id.

Comment: One option is to query the `Constraint` model when you get `constraint_id` from pivot table as `Constraint::find($constraint_id)`.

Comment: Thought about that option, but a foreach that sets the constraint object in all the post objects doesn't feel that great. You should think there would be a better way in Laravel.

Comment: That'll kill your table, if you got a thousand results it would mean that you're getting thousand new eloquent queries to your database. What you could do is loop through your data in your service, join all the contraint_ids in an array and do a simple query where the ID of the contraint is in the array. Would return 1 massive array with all your contraints. Either return these values or simply join them together and return 1 of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is 'Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns'. More information about this you will find at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-access-data-of-a-pivot-table or https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many